# Raphael clip-rect issues with text in IE8/9

Tags: raphael

Afternoon,

I'm trying to apply a clip-rect to some text within Raphael 1.5.2, with little success. It works fine on FF, Chrome and even IE6, but doesn't appear to clip on IE8 or 8.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/nC7eb) that illustrates the problem.

Is anyone aware of a workaround, other than move to Raphael 2?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Use  `clip-path`, not `clip-rect`.

Comment: I think that it's SVG specific though, so I'm not sure it's the solution. I'll give it a go though. Thanks a lot.